# Standards compliant MySQL boilerplate for all sessions

Tags: mysql

Please bear with me as I discuss other programming languages.

- Visual Basic best practice is to use boilerplate `Option Explicit` at the top of every file to avoid errors, source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260844(v=vs.60).aspx
- JavaScript best practice is to use boilerplate `"use strict"` at the top of every file (still seeking canonical source)

So my question is: Is there a widely-recognized or officially-sanctioned boilerplate option that I should include in all MySQL sessions to avoid errors?

Comment: Because goddamn, our DBAs and programmers will break stuff *all day* if we don't slow them down. The best I can hope for is that they only break stuff part of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this qualifies as an exact answer, but one best practice you could employ with MySQL is to make sure that the `ANSI` MySQL server mode is enabled for each session.  From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important):

> Equivalent to REAL_AS_FLOAT, PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ANSI_QUOTES, IGNORE_SPACE, and (as of MySQL 5.7.5) ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
>
> ANSI mode also causes the server to return an error for queries where a set function S with an outer reference S(outer_ref) cannot be aggregated in the outer query against which the outer reference has been resolved.

ANSI mode will engender MySQL queries which are more likely to run across other databases.  The ANSI mode is actually a combination of modes, which includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  This group by mode enforces that aggregation queries are ANSI compliant.  This is generally good database practice, and again also increases the chances that a MySQL query would port to another database relatively easily.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Do Wordpress and other major project currently conform to this stricter standard?

Comment: @FullDecent It is not an issue of conforming but rather what server mode you choose when using MySQL with Wordpress.  [Here is a blog](https://www.vanimpe.eu/2011/11/13/use-only_full_group_by-with-wordpress/) which shows a way to set `ANSI` mode with Wordpress.